# Oauth1.0a Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I am trying to intergrate Trade Me's api with my Angular app but I keep getting error 401.

This is the format the [api reference](https://developer.trademe.co.nz/api-overview/authorisation/) gives:

Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="", oauth_token="", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_signature="&"

```
getInfo() {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set("Authorization", "OAuth consumerKey consumerSecret oauthToken oauthSecret");

  this.http.get("https://api.tmsandbox.co.nz/v1/Categories/1.json", {headers})
    .subscribe(data => this.users.push(data));

  this.http.get("https://api.tmsandbox.co.nz/v1/MyTradeMe/SellingItems/All.json", {headers})
    .subscribe(data => this.users.push(data))
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want Oauth 1.0a? that sounds like a brutally old version. 2.0 was released in 2013

Comment: Are you sending that to the authentication endpoint documented [here](https://developer.trademe.co.nz/api-overview/authentication/)? Also as an aside: OAuth1 in 2020??